# Python's treetaggerwrapper does not recognize numbers

Tags: python, stems

I'm using treetaggerwrapper to stem Italian texts and I'm interested in the final lemmas. As you can see, while other parts of speech are transformed correctly, all numbers are changed to @card@. Is it possible to leave them unchanged?

```
import treetaggerwrapper
from pprint import pprint


tagger=treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGDIR='/home/myname/treetag/',TAGLANG='it')
tags_str = tagger.tag_text("Posso riconoscere i numeri come 3,4  99.9?")
tags = treetaggerwrapper.make_tags(tags_str)
pprint(tags)
```

[Tag(word='Posso', pos='VER2:fin', lemma='potere'),
Tag(word='riconoscere', pos='VER:infi', lemma='riconoscere'),
Tag(word='i', pos='ART', lemma='il'),
Tag(word='numeri', pos='NOUN', lemma='numero'),
Tag(word='come', pos='WH', lemma='come'),
Tag(word='3', pos='NUM', lemma='@card@'),
Tag(word=',', pos='PUN', lemma=','),
Tag(word='4', pos='NUM', lemma='@card@'),
Tag(word='99.9', pos='NUM', lemma='@card@'),
Tag(word='?', pos='SENT', lemma='?')]

Comment: Any reason not to just run through the list and set lemma=word if lemma=='@card@'? That seems like the quickest and easiest fix.

Comment: Thank you @Draconis. 
` 
for x in tags:
     if x.lemma=='@card@':
        x.lemma=x.word
`
gave me the error "cannot set attribute". By reading on [link](https://sourcesup.renater.fr/scm/viewvc.php/ttpw/tags/2.3/treetaggerwrapper.py?revision=150&view=markup&pathrev=150) it turns out Tag is a namedtuple thus immutable. So I had to modify treetaggerwrapper.py by changing the type of Tag, TagExtra and NotTag to recordtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is preserved in the `word` attribute, so it's easy enough to swap it back in. But as mentioned in the comments, Tag is an immutable type. So I propose a fairly straightforward list comprehension/filter:

```
def fix_numbers(tag):
    if tag.lemma == '@card@': return Tag(tag.word, tag.pos, tag.word)
    return tag

fixed_list = [fix_numbers(tag) for tag in original_list]
```